# Simplify this summation: $\sum\limits_{k=5}^\infty{\binom{k-1}{k-5}}\frac{k^3}{2^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k=5}^\infty{{k-1}\choose{k-5}}\frac{k^3}{2^k}$$

I can't seem to simplify this sum. I get to a certain point then I get stuck, I know there must be some sort of trick to simplify it but I am unsure of how to do so. Any hints would be more than helpful!

Comment: Using Mathematica the solution is 1330. see [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5Bk+-+1%2C+k+-+5%5D+k%5E3%2F2%5Ek%2C+%7Bk%2C+5%2C+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sum equals:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(j+5)^3}{32\cdot 2^j}\binom{j+4}{j}.\tag{1}$$
Since:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\binom{j+4}{j}x^j = \frac{1}{(1-x)^5},\tag{2}$$
by differentiating three times both terms of $(2)$, you get the sums $\sum_{j\geq 0}\binom{j+4}{4}j^k\,x^j$ with $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, hence recombining these pieces you get:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(j+5)^3}{32\cdot 2^j}\binom{j+4}{j}=1330.$$

Comment: Sorry, but how did you get 1/(1-x)^5 for part 2? I am still a little slow with this

Comment: It is just the binomial theorem for negative exponents: $$(1-x)^{-m}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\binom{j+m-1}{m-1}x^j.$$

Comment: To prove it, multiply both sides by $(1-x)$, use the properties of binomial coefficients and make the induction on $m$ work.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry my professor never went over negative binomials, so I'm still trying to understand it. Could you show me how the term for k=0 would look like?

Comment: Assume we want to prove: $$(1-x)^{-5}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\binom{j+4}{4}x^j.$$ By multiplying both sides by $(1-x)$, the problem boils down to prove that $$(1-x)^{-4}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\left(\binom{j+4}{4}-\binom{j+3}{4}\right)x^j=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\binom{j+3}{3}x^j.$$ Can you see the pattern now?

Comment: An upvote would have been kind, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand this distribution too well and my knowledge of it is very basic. Is there a simpler way you can explain this to me?

Comment: This is also my first time on this site, so please excuse me if I don't understand how it works, but I will try to upvote you.

Comment: Ok, let us try to prove the other way. We have $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}x^j,$ so the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n$ is just $a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_n$. This gives that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}(j+1)x^j$, and $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\binom{j+2}{2}x^j.$ Since $$\sum_{j=0}^{N}\binom{n+k}{k}=\binom{n+N+1}{N+1},$$ the claim: $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{h+1}}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\binom{j+h}{h}x^j$$ follows.

Comment: Oh that's more understandable, for my case would x^j be (j+5)^3/(32)*2^j? That's the part I am most confused on.

Comment: No way. After you have established the identity, see what happens when differentiating both terms with respect to $x$. By differentiating once: $$\frac{(h+1)}{(1-x)^{h+2}}=\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\binom{j+h}{h}j x^{j-1},$$ by differentiating twice: $$\frac{(h+1)(h+2)}{(1-x)^{h+3}}=\sum_{j=2}^{+\infty}\binom{j+h}{h}j(j-1) x^{j-2},$$ hence, in general, you can write the closed form for $$\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\binom{j+h}{h}j^\nu 2^j$$ by evaluating such derivatives in $x=2$. Finally, consider that $(j+5)^3 = j^3+15j^2+75j+125.$ Can you finish by yourself, now?

Comment: Sorry if you're getting impatient, but I tried and I can't seem to wrap my head around this concept. I can't understand why in your original answer you derived it three times and how you got k={0,1,2,3}. I still have no clue what x^j is and how to obtain an integer answer

Comment: Sorry if I seemed impatient. I will re-write my answer to include all the details, just not now. Give me some time and I will try to be more clear.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! And I did not mean imply that you were impatient, I just felt bad for asking you to go into so much detail.

Comment: Actually Jack, I got it! Thanks for everything though. I would upvote but it require me to have 15 reputation and I haven't quite reached that limit.